# Return a part of regular expression with egrep on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I'm wondering if I can select only a part of a regular expression with egrep on Ubuntu.

If I do this:

```
wget -qO- http://nodejs.org/download/ | egrep -o -m 1 'Current version: <b>v(.*)</b>'
```

It returned me this:

```
Current version: <b>v0.10.28</b>
```

But I only need the version number:

```
0.10.28
```

How can I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep -P` (PCRE):

```
wget -qO- http://nodejs.org/download/ | grep -oP -m 1 'Current version: <b>v\K(.*?)(?=</b>)'
```